# Etymology of 急須

Tags: etymology

A 急須 (kyūsu) is a teapot. If you are really thirsty you may feel an urgent need for one, but otherwise the etymology is not self-evident.

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/急須#Japanese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%80%A5%E9%A0%88#Japanese) lacks etymological information, but does show that the word exists in Chinese with the same meaning. So perhaps this is a question of Chinese, rather than Japanese, etymology.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (no idea about its validity):「急須」という呼び名は、青木正児によれば、「急須」は中国・呉（蘇州地方）の方言で酒を温める器、「急焼・急尾焼[3]」は福建の方言で湯を沸かす器のことという

Answer (score 2):

I remember 急須{きゅうす} was also pronounced "きびしょう" before. I have remembered the pot was called like that but it was also used for soysauce-serving in my experience. And it closes to the hypothesis that its origin is [sake-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sake_set) from china.

I found [this site](http://www.yamaderakk.co.jp/kyuusu1.html) :「現代急須の世界　精巧な急須その起源と歴史についての考察
　温故焼、万古焼、常滑焼 地理的必然性」and [the question](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13114235578) in 「Yahoo知恵袋 : 私の地方では急須（きゅうす）の事をきびしょと言いますが」 useful for the question.

The excerpt of first passage from the site :

> 急須は、以前きびしょと言われていました。きびしょから急須へ何時ごろ呼び名が代わったのかはっきりしません。一般にきびしょは方言と考えられていますが、実際の語源は酒器の急焼、急火焼(きびしょう)だとも言われています。一方急須ですが「須」が用の同義語それから急須の呼び名ができたとの研究もあります。江戸時代涼炉とボーフラが輸入されていました。ボーフラ(湯沸し)が急須と兼用されていた、散茶の発展とともに専用の物として「急焼」きゅうしょうーきびしょうーきゅうすと独立したものになっていったと思われます。涼炉とかボーフラは、煎茶の道具になる前は、中国ではコンロ、酒器だったと思われます。日本の急須は、ボーフラから進化したので横手のものが多くなったと考えられます。
>   個人的な意見ですが須は、Necesstiy　
>   The necessities of lifee"生活必需品"になればと考えています。
>   急須は、煎茶道では昔から「茶銚」「茶注」と呼ばれています。

You perhaps could add the "kanji" tags for the further detailed answer.